# from an input field to an output div- javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

```
<script>
    function func()
    {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML + "drew";
    }
</script>
```

with this code of mine i intended to add the word "drew" at the end of whole text in `<div>` with id="demo" on a button click which appeared before the `<div>` in HTML code. the desired output showed up for fraction of a second and again the value in `<div>` restored back to what it was before function call. I have got no clue about how to solve the issue, yet, I guess it happened because the div appears again in code, after the button was clicked, and changes the value to the initial one.So i seek for help here.

Comment: Your code works, but can be simplified with `+=` operator. Probably you have some other code which breaks it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works perfectly fine. May be you need to call it this way. Check if you are using this as the right way?

```js
function func()
{
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML + "drew";
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">You </div>
<button onclick="func()">Check</button>
```